# Determine set of "arbitrage-free" regional prices

Tags: linear-programming, quadratic-programming, pricing

I am seeking for a way how to determine set of "arbitrage-free" regional prices for a single commodity market.

- There are $N>1$ production units with costs $C^{prod}_i, i=1,\dots,N$ and limited production capacities $P_i^{max}$. There are no fixed costs.
- There are $M>1$ consumers sitting in different regions with fix demands of $D_j, j=1,\dots,M$. Total demand is smaller than total supply so that some producers are not producing.
- There is a transportation cost matrix $C^{tr}_{ij}$ for shipping from producers to consumers

How do I find a set of equilibrium regional prices that:

1. Maximize profits of producers
2. Match "rational" behavior (most expensive producer sells to marginal costs)
3. Individual producers cannot increase their profits by increasing sale prices because they would loose market share due to activation of concurrents

I found some literature [describing "spatial equilibrium"](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-74759-0_628) which sounds similar to what I am looking for. Somehow I cannot formulate my problem's objective (market welfare). Can you help me or direct in a right direction?

What i tried so far:

- introduced common sales price for each producer $p_i^{prod}$ which is used for all "shipments". In case if producer is activated it is set to at least $C^{prod}_i$, $p_i^{prod}\geq used_i\cdot C^{prod}_i$
- introduced regional sales prices $p_i^{cons}$ which are limited from below by the cost of shipments used to serve demand. This introduces binary "is shipping" variables $s_{ij}$ for each producer-consumer link. $p_i^{cons} \geq p_j^{prod} + C^{tr}_{ij}\cdot s_{ij} - (1-s_{ij})\cdot BigM, \forall j$.
- defined welfare function as $\sum_{ij} (p_i^{prod} - C^{tr}_{ij} - C^{prod}_i)\cdot q_{ij} - \sum_j D_j \cdot p_j^{cons}$
- Tried to maximize it

There are several issues with my approach:

- Problem is MIP
- Problem is QP
- Objective seems to be non-convex as reported by CPLEX

There must be something that i am missing..

Comment: I believe you have a typo: "Total demand is smaller than total demand".

Comment: Do you know that there is a convex formulation? is this a school assignment or a research problem?

Comment: I do not know if there is a convex formulation or not. It is a research problem targeting at estimation of equilibrium market prices.

Comment: CPLEX and Gurobi can (attempt to) solve non-convex MIQPs to global optimality. Also more general purpose MINLP solvers, such as BARON. they may not do it as quickly as you'd like, but you can give it a shot and at last examine how the solutions come out. Then you can try to improve the formulation.

Comment: I found description of "reactive programming" algorithm which solves similar problem dated to 80s of last century [manual](https://ideas.repec.org/p/ags/ncbuar/259740.html). List of properties of problem "solution" is rather straight-forward. I am thinking about whether i should reimplement it as-is or if i can try reformulating it in form of QP (here i run again against difficulty in formulation of model objective)

Comment: This problem is similar to how electricity markets operate subject to transmission constraints (the *Unit Commitment* problem). A set of $N$ consumers needs to satisfy demand at $M$ locations with transmission constraints imposed by the physical grid. The objective is to maximize the social welfare. If no transmission constraint is imposed, then there is a single *marginal* price, else a different marginal price is set for each node, equal to the respective Langrage multiplier. I am not sure if this relevant for your case. A standard reference: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2555444?seq=1